# Difference in exit(num) in java

Tags: java, syntax, exit

I used `exit()` in my java program and it just exits the executing program. But I don't understand the difference between types of exits!!

Such as for example

```
exit(0)
exit(1)
exit(2)
```

..so on. Can anyone share info about this?

Comment: It simply returns exit value to the operating system. The OS can use different exit values to perform different operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value means nothing for the Java program itself. The shell calling the Java program can use it to determine what to do next.

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) `public static void exit(int status)` terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a `status code`; **by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination**.

Answer (score 2):

That is called the [exit status or return code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). It tells the shell whether your program ran without error (return code `0`) or with an error (any other return code value, which one you choose indicates the type of error.)

Answer (score 2):

A non zero reurn code indicates abnormal termination (by convention). Moreover you can return different non-zero values to indicate the cause of terminating the program, so that its easier to debug/identify the error.

Look at the documentation : [System class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)